# Can AWS Lambda Speak to external Internet Services?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

With the ground breaking revolutionary fully managed functional programming support by AWS; can AWS lambda speak to external internet / systems for external communication.

The idea / motive is if AWS Lambda use the NodeJS SDK for services PubNub, Pusher - it would be nice to offload the handler aspect of the real time communication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Since Lambda runs in a Node sandbox, there's nothing stopping you from bundling up something like [request](https://github.com/request/request) and using it from within your function. However, there are a few limitations to consider:

1. There is a hard upper limit of 60 seconds for execution, so if your requests take too long your function could timeout
2. Lambda places some restrictions on network capabilities:

   > Inbound network connections are managed by AWS Lambda, only TCP/IP
   >   sockets are supported, and ptrace (debugging) system calls are
   >   restricted.

Comment: In addition, someone posted a [Function to send an SMS message via the Twilio API](https://gist.github.com/stevebowman/7cff9dd80b227c899728)

Comment: Do you have a link to where you snagged that documentation from? Having a hard time finding the right docs.