# How to call web service from Alexa Lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I want to make a GET request to a web site using the Amazon Profile API.  I am trying to do what is described in the last code chunk in this article: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/Alexa-Account-Linking-5-Steps-to-Seamlessly-Link-Your-Alexa-Skill-with-Login-wit (very end of article)  and it just does not happen.  My callback function never seems to get called.

I have added the required context.succeed(), actually the latest version of that, and am still not getting results.  I know the url is good, as I can take it and copy/paste into a browser and it returns an expected result.

Here is a SO answer on using the appropriate context function calls within the callback, which I have tried.   [Why is this HTTP request not working on AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449363/why-is-this-http-request-not-working-on-aws-lambda)

I am not using a VPC.

What am I doing wrong?  I feel like a moron, as I have been researching this and trying solutions for 2 days.  I log the full URL, and when I copy/paste that out of the log file, and put it in a browser window, I do get a valid result. Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
function getUserProfileInfo(token, context) {

console.log("IN getUserProfileInfo");

var request = require('request');

var amznProfileURL = 'https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token=';

amznProfileURL += token;

console.log("calling it");

console.log(amznProfileURL);

console.log("called it");


request(amznProfileURL, function(error, response, body) {

if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

var profile = JSON.parse(body);

console.log("IN getUserProfileInfo success");

console.log(profile);

context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; 
callback(null, 'Success message');

} else {

console.log("in getUserProfileInfo fail");

console.log(error);

context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; 
callback('Fail object', 'Failed result'); 
}
});

console.log("OUT getUserProfileInfo");

}
```

This is the logging output I get in CloudWatch:

2017-03-08T22:20:53.671Z 7e393297-044d-11e7-9422-39f5f7f812f6 IN getUserProfileInfo 
2017-03-08T22:20:53.728Z 7e393297-044d-11e7-9422-39f5f7f812f6 OUT getUserProfileInfo

Comment: Maybe you should post the log output, omitting any secrets.

Comment: I have added relevant log output.

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be that you are using `var request = require('request');` which is external dependency and will require you to make a packaged lambda deployment for it to work. See this answer for relevant information.

> [AWS Node JS with Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848877/aws-node-js-with-request/42877352#42877352)

Another way is that you can use NodeJS module such as `var http= require('http');` which is builtin module to make the requests. This way you can just make plain lambda script deployment.

Reference

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html