# Issues when deploying my serverless project in windows

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have created a serverless boilerplate project using this command

> sls create --template aws-nodejs-typescript --path my-project

I configured properly my AWS credantials thus I was able to depoly it successfully without any problem

> sls deploy

But when I test de **hello** function I get the following error (after executing **sls logs -f hello**)

> ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot
> find  module 'handler'\nRequire stack:\n-
> /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n-
> /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error:
> Cannot find module 'handler '","Require stack:","-
> /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at
> _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.ex ports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","
> at Object. (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js :999:30)","    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Func
> tion.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at
> Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at intern
> al/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]} END RequestId:
> 28588f41-1c4c-4391-82da-0c89bc1f9707 REPORT RequestId:
> 28588f41-1c4c-4391-82da-0c89bc1f9707  Duration: 164.91 ms     Billed
> Duration: 165 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 15 MB
>
> Unknown application error occurred Runtime.ImportModuleError

I think  the problem is in the **Windows** environment, because when I deploy the service with **Mac** it works with no issue ! Did I need an extra-configuration to use Serverless with windows ? Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serverless Framework with AWS Lambda error "Cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880987/serverless-framework-with-aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module)

Comment: @esqew still having the same issue althought I have no error while doing the ''npm install'' !