# Cannot Find Module with Serverless

Tags: typescript, graphql, serverless, apollo-server

I am using Typescript, ApolloServer, graphql, serverless, and Lambdas to build out my application. When running a `sls offline start` I am getting the following error:

```
offline: Failure: Cannot find module '/Users/aroe/Desktop/projects/test-serverless-backend/functions/graph/graphql'
Require stack:
```

Here is my serverless.yml config

```js
service: gamitrak-backend # service name
provider:
  name: aws # deploy to AWS
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  versionFunctions: false # disable function versioning
  region: us-west-2 # AWS region
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true

functions:
  graph:
    handler: /src/functions/graph/graphql.handler # Lambda handler path
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql # define Lambda endpoint
          method: any # any HTTP method can access this Lambda
          cors: true # enable CORS
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Under handler: we can see that it's trying to hit my function, here is that file when running a PWD command to show path

```
/Users/aroe/Desktop/projects/test-serverless-backend/src/functions/graph
```

Here is the actual meat of the code that's attempting to be hit:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-lambda';
import { usersTypeDefs, usersResolvers } from './schema/users';

// get the GraphQL schema

// resolver functions

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs: usersTypeDefs, resolvers: usersResolvers });

// launch the server when the Lambda is called
export async function handler(_event: any, _context: any) {
  const handler = server.createHandler();
  console.log(handler);
  return handler;
}
```

My inclination is to think that it cannot hit the file for some reason? However, I am not sure why/how?

Here is all the version information for my stack in case it's relevant as to what serverless version I'm using.

Framework Core: 2.70.0
Plugin: 5.5.2
SDK: 4.3.0
Components: 3.18.1

Thank you all so much in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880987/serverless-framework-with-aws-lambda-error-cannot-find-module