# Automatically retrieve JSON data via URL every X second and store in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for an easy way to retrieve and store JSON in Amazon DynamoDB.
I'm getting the data via an URL and I would like to query the URL every X second - example:
wget http://open-stocks.com/api/get-data-10:21:33.json

The time in the URL should match time of request - so that's dynamic.

I guess I could spin up an entire Linux server on AWS and write a Python script generating the URL, getting the data and push it to Amazon DynamoDB - but I would love a sort of existing service, which made me not worrying about server OS, cronjobs etc...

Any help to such service, perhaps directly via AWS?

Comment: I think scheduled AWS Lambdas could be a way forward -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616205/run-scheduled-task-in-aws-without-cron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS Lambda now supports [Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks). Since Lambda [can make HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521169/can-aws-lamdba-speak-to-external-internet-services/27932216#27932216) and [write to DynamoDB](https://gist.github.com/markusklems/1e7218d76d7583f1f7b3), using Lambda should work and you don't have to worry about setting up an EC2 instance with a cron job just for that.

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking for :)