# Using Amazon Lambda fails with python example and S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use Amazon Lambda for getting data from an URL and store the content in S3. Related to this: [Automatically retrieve JSON data via URL every X second and store in Amazon DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672521/automatically-retrieve-json-data-via-url-every-x-second-and-store-in-amazon-dyna)

This is my code so far:

```
from time import strftime
import urllib2, boto3

timekey = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://open-stocks.com/api/get-data-' + time + '.json')
data = response.read()

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('my-stocks-bucket').put_object(Key=timekey, Body=data)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
module initialization error:
An error occurred (PermanentRedirect) when calling the PutObject operation:
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.
Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

What to do? I've not entered any credentials for my bucket, but it's on the same AWS user I've got my Lambda function and Buckets...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently bucket and lambda function needs to be in the same region. Now things work.

Comment: In some cases you need to add the resources to the same VPC.